# Moving automated emails into a different tab in Gmail

Tags: email, gmail

My current company sends out these automated emails containing updates to certain machines. These emails just contain these really boring reports that I don't really care too much for.
I'd like them to go into the "Updates" tab instead of the "Primary" tab. Every time I get an email in the "Primary" tab, it gives my phone a notification, which gets pretty annoying if it's hourly. If it went into the Updates tab, it would not give my phone a notification.

Is there a header or something that I can send in the email so that it goes into the Updates tab? I understand I can do it manually (by creating a rule), but it would be easier if it can be done via an email header (or alike), so that when I add more Gmail users, they don't need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the [Gmail user](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016?hl=en). There is no way senders can force their way into which tab their emails go to by default. If this was the case, there would be no point of the Promotions tab as everyone would be gunning for the Primary tab.